# NAS-сервер не виден в другой стране

Tags: сервер, http, веб-сервер, веб-сайт, nas

Я развернул веб-сервер на своем NAS (QNAP).

У интернет-провайдера арендовал статический IPv4.

Домен привязал (http://smshero.download).

Маршрутизацию роутера настроил.

**ПРОБЛЕМА:** В пределах Украины с подключением нет никаких проблем, но вот в других странах сайт почему-то не открывается, и даже прямые ссылки на скачивание файлов не работают. Более того, по IP-адресу, на который ссылается домен, сайт не открывается вообще нигде в мире (включая Украину).

Звонил интернет-провайдеру, спрашивал о блокировках портов с его стороны, но он бьет себя в грудь уверяя в том, что с его стороны точно_железно_стопудово нет никаких блокировок ни портов, ни чего-либо еще, зуб_даю_век-воли-не-видать...

Адрес "smshero.download" без проблем пингуется из командной строки во всех странах. Да и по IP-адресу тоже пингуется нормально... То есть, сайт не открывается, ссылки не работают, но сам адрес пингуется нормально.

Еще интереснее тот факт, что используя VPN региона Украина сайт можно открыть в любой стране мира.

Скриншоты команд ping/tracert по IP-адресу:

```
В Украине: prnt.sc/061iaoYx_vhz 
В Финляндии: prnt.sc/-0MoE9EBSd8y
```

Скриншот WinMTR по домену из Финляндии:

```
https://prnt.sc/l1YdrAeuJgSy
```

В чем может быть дело?

---

**Update:**

Tracert изменился. Не знаю почему, но вот так он выглядит сейчас:

```
tracert 37.57.121.241

Трассировка маршрута к 241.121.57.37.triolan.net [37.57.121.241]
с максимальным числом прыжков 30:

  1    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  static.65.143.108.65.clients.your-server.de [65.108.143.65]
  2    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  core32.hel1.hetzner.com [213.239.252.53]
  3    <1 мс    <1 мс    <1 мс  juniper5.dc1.hel1.hetzner.com [213.239.203.210]
  4     1 ms     *        1 ms  185.1.160.117
  5     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  6     8 ms     8 ms     9 ms  port-channel2.core2.rix1.he.net [184.104.192.94]
  7    12 ms    12 ms    12 ms  100ge5-1.core1.vno1.he.net [184.104.192.90]
  8     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
  9     *        *       34 ms  port-channel2.core2.kbp1.he.net [184.104.192.166]
 10     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
 11    42 ms    40 ms    38 ms  triolan-kiev-gw.fiord.net [62.140.255.51]
 12    41 ms    39 ms    39 ms  az-international-llc.100gigabitethernet11-1.core1.waw1.he.net [65.49.80.226]
 13     *        *        *     Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
 14    43 ms    43 ms    43 ms  triolan.114.ett.ua [78.154.176.114]
 15    42 ms    42 ms    43 ms  241.121.57.37.triolan.net [37.57.121.241]

Трассировка завершена.
```

Comment: А по айпишнику зайти на сайт позволяет?

Comment: Хмм... Нет, не позволяет даже в Украине. Странно...
Хотя IP указан верно. Да и такие сервисы, как "2ip" явно указывают, что за моим доменом закреплен именно данный IP. Но по домену сайт открывается в Украине, а по IP не открывается вообще нигде.
Есть догадки почему так?))

Comment: Зависит от настроек веб сервера. Ну хотя бы пинг/трасерт идет?

Comment: А вы уверены, что по домену действительно открывается, а не, например, из кэша браузера какая-нибудь старая страничка отображается или типа того? Там, где открывается, проверяли, что домен резолвится в правильный IP-адрес, а не в какой-нибудь 127.0.0.1 из файла hosts или типа того?

Comment: В Украине: https://prnt.sc/061iaoYx_vhz
В Финляндии: https://prnt.sc/-0MoE9EBSd8y

Comment: Страница открывается ТОЧНО не из кеша.
У меня 20 компьютеров (серверов) расположены в разных городах Украины, и все они без проблем подключаются к данному ресурсу за получением обновлений моей программы.
А когда возникла необходимость доступа из других стран - тут и всплыла на поверхность данная проблема.

Comment: Странно. На данный момент имеем такую картину:
Домен пингуется по всем мире. IP-адрес тоже пингуется по всем мире.
Tracert также показывает вполне адекватную картину.
НО!...
Сайт по домену открывается только в Украине, а по IP не открывается вообще нигде в мире (включая Украину).

Похоже, что проблема в настройках самого веб-сервера, однако в админ-панели NAS-сервера (QNAP) не так уж много настроек, с которыми можно было натупить...

Comment: tracert почему-то изменился. Я обновил пост.

Comment: Забавный факт: вы можете открыть сайт в любой стране мира, используя украинский VPN))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что мой IP-адрес (от интернет-провайдера) находится в блек-листах трех DNS-серверов.